# How to implement IIdentity when my system doesn't use "usernames"?

Tags: .net, identity, claims-based-identity

I'm surprised the `IIdentity` interface in .NET makes certain design assumptions about the host security environment, number 1 is that the system uses Names.

I imagine this makes sense for the majority of applications, especially traditional computer security where each user has a username as its primary identifier, of course on NT the `SId` (NT Security Identifier) is the real ID.

This design assumes usernames are immutable: what happens when a user's username is changed concurrently? The `IIdentity.Name` property is read-only, making it immutable in code.

But chiefly, the design also assumes that usernames are used at all. What about systems that avoid string-based names and use an explicit integer-based user ID, or something more exotic like GUIDs? It doesn't feel right to implement it as `String Name { get { return this.UserId.ToStringInvariant(); } }`.

Going deeper, how do you deal with a "composite identity" where the current security context is decided by not only the user's authentication details, but also his current client software, his network location, and other aspects? Granted, those can be considered just more examples of claims (and I'm thankful that `ClaimsIdentity` is now the base implementation in .NET 4.5) but claims are all `string`-based in .NET 4.5, if you have a complex object-graph as part of a claim you need to hackishly convert it to some string representation (or 2-dimensional string representation in `Claim.Properties`) and hope that works.

In the old-school of .NET 1.0-3.5, I would just implement `IIdentity` by returning a username for `Name` (fortunately every project I've worked on always had at least some analogue for a username, sometimes very tenuous) and then adding additional "claims" as strongly-typed properties in my implementation, including complex object-graph property values.

...is that necessarily correct? Is there any infrastructure code in .NET which makes assumptions on the nature of `IIdentity`?

Answer (score 0):

The `IIdentity` interface doesn't assume any format to the username, and it is really just a unique identifier for an identity, so any string (like a GUID) would work. With .Net 4.5, we have claims providers which allow you to represent an identity with just the username (unique id) and the set of key/value pairs called claims. Yes, the key/value decomposition is a very loose pile of data, but it has the advantage of flexibility, allowing the identity system to add claims to the identity in any way the receiving application (aka relying party) needs. Any classes in the framework as of .Net 4.5 which rely on an `IIdentity` should also describe which claims need to be present, and you can configure your Identity Provider to add these, or use the claims provider infrastructure to add them during authentication or authorization.